# How to create a JQuery nav bar?

Tags: jquery, hide, show, show-hide

I have a site with 6 nav buttons down the side.  For each of them, I want to show the corresponding DIV hide the other 5. The page loads with DIV #1 visible and the others display:none.

I know how to hide and show elements with hide(), show(), fade etc. but I am trying to come up with the best way to seamlessly show the clicked one while simultaneously hiding whichever one is currently visible, without resorting to spelling them all out like:

```
$('#btn1').click(function(){
$('#div2').hide();
$('#div3').hide();
$('#div1').show();
 )}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the jquery code:

```
      $(document).ready(function() {
          $('#btn-next').click(function () {
          $('#recent_post').hide();
           $('#top_post').fadeIn(3000).show();
           return false;        
            }); 
        $('#btn-prev').click(function () {
        $('#top_post').hide();
        $('#recent_post').fadeIn(3000).show();
            return false;   
        }); 
        });
```

Here is the html:

```
    <div id="top_post" class="post" style="z-index:1;">
       <!---Content goes here--->
     </div>
    <div class="post" id="recent_post" style="display:none;z-index:0;">
       <!---Content goes here--->
     </div>
```

I have implemented it in my website.Visit 'articles' section in http://kaidul.web44.net/
I have just built it for two divs.Do the same work for 6 divs.Hope it works !

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.commonBtn').click(function(){ // commonBtn is common class to all buttons
   var index = this.id.replace('btn','');
   $('div[id^=div]:visible').hide();
   $('#div'+ index).show();
)};
```

Answer (score 1):

Use buttons' ids like `btn_1` instead of `btn1`

```
$('div[id^="btn"]').click(function(){
    var id = $(this).attr("id").split("_")[1]; // fetch the id's number part

    $('div[id^="div"]').hide(); // hide all divs with id starting with div

    $("#div"+id).show(); // show corresponding div     

 )}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I wound up doing.  If the nav buttons are named things like "dc" that div that gets hidden and shown was named "dcdiv"

```
 var which_id;

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#rightcontent>div:not(.default)").hide();  // hide all client divs but default one
        $("#clientnav li").click(onClick); // event handler for nav bar

        function doTransition(){
            var which_name = which_id.split("#")[1];
            $('#clientnav li[id="'+which_name+'"]').addClass("active");
            $("#rightcontent>div:visible").slideUp("fast", function(){
                var which_div = which_id+'div';
                $(which_div).slideDown("fast");
            });
        }

        function onClick(event){
            $('#clientnav li').removeClass("active"); // remove active class for all nav buttons
            which_id = "#" + $(this).attr("id"); // get the id of the nav button clicked on
            doTransition();
            event.preventDefault();
        };
```